# eRCP for mobiles

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I saw good articles on eRCP to create widgets for Mobile/PDA applications.
So it for creating the our own applications like Sudoko games,etc for mobiles 
or Is it for creating the Widgets for mobiles? like all the menus(contact menu,message menu,etc) or in the mobiles are 
being developed using this eRCP?I just wanted to get good idea on this.

Also,I just would like to know some mobiles phones which have already implemented using eRCP technology.

Note: Dont know which is the right tag for asking this topic.

Thanks
Bhanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eRCP was for Symbian and Windows CE, it isn't actively developed any more.